# Can several if and else if statements are written in one line? C#

Tags: c#

In this method, I tried to convert decimal numbers to any base. This method works well.
I have used two nested `if` statements. There are 7 modes in the internal statement.
My teacher asked me to write all these `if` statements in one line.
Is there a way?
I know about the `?:` statement but I have to use just one of these statements.

```cs
private string Converting(int a, int b)
{
    string result = string.Empty;
    int remaining;

    // start while loop statement
    while (a > 0)
    {
        remaining = a % b; 

        // start if else statement to validate value of b
        if (b >= 11 && b <= 16)
        {           
            if (remaining == 10)
            {
                result += 'A';
            }
            else if (remaining == 11)
            {
                result += 'B';
            }
            else if (remaining == 12)
            {
                result += 'C';
            }
            else if (remaining == 13)
            {
                result += 'D';
            }
            else if (remaining == 14)
            {
                result += 'E';
            }
            else if (remaining == 15)
            {
                result += 'F';
            }
            else
            {
                result += remaining;
            } 
        }
        else
        {
            result += remaining;
        } 

        a /= b;
    } 

    return new string(result.ToCharArray().Reverse().ToArray());
}
```

Comment: Use `switch` statement

Comment: or a `Dictionary<int, string>` that maps each input to its corresponding text value

Comment: @David Pivovar This statement cannot be written in one line

Comment: @MehdiGhomshe why would that matter? Even if it was written in one line it would be unmaintainable. Yes, you can have one line but everyone would hate you. Use an array or Dictionary instead. And *don't concatenate strings*. Every such operation creates a new temporary string

Comment: @MehdiGhomshe i'm curious how your _teacher_ intends to write those ifs in one line, btw.

Comment: That entire function could be replaced with [`Convert.ToString`?](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.convert.tostring?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=net-5.0#System_Convert_ToString_System_Int32_System_Int32_)

Comment: You can eliminate all those `if`s with `remaining.ToString("X")`

Answer (score 3):

You could convert the remaining to a char:

```
if (remaining >= 10)
{
    result += (char)('A' + remaining - 10);
}
else
{
    result += remaining;
}
```

In a single line:

```
result += remaining >= 10 ? (char)('A' + remaining - 10) : remaining;
```

Or extract from a string:

```
result += "0123456789ABCDEF"[remaining]
```

Comment: with if-else statement works well for any base but with a single line for base more than 10, words do not display